# Mobile site version shows incorrect number of bounties in User's profile (summary)

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, mobile-web

While visiting users profiles from mobile I've noticed that the number of bounties in profile summary for users with more than 5 bounties earned is always 5 and to see correct number bounties section need to be viewed.

[image: profile summary]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch, this was also broken in the full version if you had more than 30.  The fix applies to both and will be rolled out in the next build.